# Python: Simple log-in and filling form

Tags: python, spynner

*Hi.
I usually don't ask, because I find or solve everything myself. But in this trouble I'm tormented for many hours, even if that is really easy task.*

In Python, I need to log in to some social network, add new post, copy link of that new post and fill Google Docs form with that link + some personal info.

I tried Mechanize, Spynner and Selenium, but still no way. Spynner looks like best variant, I have done login into social network and filling Google Docs form. But after I log into social network, I don't know how to add new post. (Currently I'm trying to do it on VK.com.) Maybe I'm typing bad name of form...

My current code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
import spynner
b = spynner.Browser()
b.show()
b.load('http://vk.com')
b.wk_fill('input[name=email]', 'my@email.tld')
b.wk_fill('input[name=pass]', 'mypassword')
b.click("#quick_login_button")
b.wait_load()
# ▼ This is not working ▼
b.wk_fill('input[name=post_field]', 'This is the new post.')
b.click("#send_post")
b.browse() # To see the result
```

Comment: Why don't you use the API instead? http://vk.com/dev

Comment: I try that, but it's not the best solution for me...

Comment: Any ideas? I only need modify this line: "b.wk_fill('input[name=post_field]', 'This is the new post.')"